# filter array of dictionaries with two strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nspredicate

For search dropdown table I need to show the "Description" and "SearchTerms" in cell textlabel and detailed Textlabel respectively. I need to implement the filter which is based on two strings i.e search text should be compare with the both "Description" and "SearchTerms". I tried NSPredicate but it can filter for one string only

```
NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:searchServiceTextField.text];
NSLog(@"substring %@",substring);
NSMutableArray *arr2Filt= [searchArray valueForKey:@"Description"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF  contains[c] %@",substring];
NSArray *filteredarr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[arr2Filt filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
NSLog(@"filtered array %@",filteredarr);
```

i tried to modify for both the strings but i didn't get better soultion.

```
  [{
        Description = "Rental Jewellery, Jewellery for events";
        ProfessionId = "<null>";
        SKUFormat = "<null>";
        SearchTerms = "Rental Jewellery";
        SpecialityId = 62;
        tokens = "<null>";
        value = "<null>";
    },
    {
        Description = "Kids Party with Food and Games Venues";
        ProfessionId = "<null>";
        SKUFormat = "<null>";
        SearchTerms = "Party Venue";
        SpecialityId = 63;
        tokens = "<null>";
        value = "<null>";
    },
    {
        Description = "Music, Dance, Sports classes";
        ProfessionId = "<null>";
        SKUFormat = "<null>";
        SearchTerms = Classes;
        SpecialityId = 64;
        tokens = "<null>";
        value = "<null>";
    },
    {
        Description = "Zumba, Yoga, Aerobics classes";
        ProfessionId = "<null>";
        SKUFormat = "<null>";
        SearchTerms = "Fitness/Health";
        SpecialityId = 65;
        tokens = "<null>";
        value = "<null>";
    }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like

```
NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:searchServiceTextField.text];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Description contains[c] %@ AND SearchTerms contains[c] %@",substring, substring];
NSArray * filteredarr =[[searchArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] copy];

NSLog(@"filtered array %@",filteredarr);
```